# How comes this bounty was awarded?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, bounty

I placed a bounty around November 2014 to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15168803/keyevent-action-up-fired-twice-for-action-media-button) (NOT mine), asked and answered more than a year before, because none of the answers (including the accepted one) looked satisfying to me (why is not relevant here, however, basically the answer was based on some assumption that was not the case for me, yet I was observing the same issue).

No answer was added after I placed the bounty. According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty):

> If you do not award your bounty within 7 days (plus the grace period),
>   the highest voted answer **created after** the bounty started with a
>   minimum score of 2 will be awarded half the bounty amount. If two or
>   more eligible answers have the same score (their scores are tied), the
>   oldest answer is chosen. **If there's no answer meeting those criteria,
>   no bounty is awarded to anyone** [emphasis added].

no bounty should have been awarded. However, I notice that half the bounty amount was awarded to the accepted answer which already existed before the bounty started; it wasn't even edited afterwards (by the way, it would seem reasonable that the rule applied also to an existing answer edited after the bounty started, but the above text doesn't say anything about that either).

So this seems to contradict the stated rules (which by the way I remember reading at that time and I don't seem to remember they were any different). Am I missing something?

It's not that I care about the reputation, I know I was loosing the 50 points anyway and I don't care who gains 25 points if I (as the bounty creator, not the asker) don't get a better answer. I just hate when things don't work as documented.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This isn't a bug and the bounty system is working as expected. The question has had [2 bounties](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/15168803/revisions) placed on it.

One in 2013, which was auto-awarded by the community.  That's the one you see on the accepted answer.

Your bounty in 2014 was not awarded because no answer met the criteria to win it.

Comment: Oh I see, thanks. I think information about the bounty should be accessible through some link near to the "+25" sign next to the answer, as opposed to in the edit history of the question, which is a place where it wouldn't have occurred to me to look for such information.

Comment: @matteo Its also available on the [timeline](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/15168803/timeline) for the post.